# How to exit the view source mode in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

In Vimperator when I hit <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> it takes me to view source. how do I exit view source and come back to actual web page?

Answer (score 19):

My bad. A <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> again on the source page takes back to the actual page